# how to traverse on white pixels on image and add nodes after every two pixel and connect that nodes using edges

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graph-theory

every one i am doing my project on A Novel Graph Database for Handwritten Word Images in that am doing on {Graph Extraction – Keypoint (Node Extraction)}

Alogithm

```
Input: Skeleton image S, Distance threshold D
Output: Graph g = (V, E) with nodes V and edges E
1: function Keypoint(S,D)
2: for Each connected component CC ∈ S do
3: V = V ∪ {(x, y) ∈ CC | (x, y) are end- or junction points}
4: Remove junction points from CC
5: for Each connected subcomponent CCsub ∈ CC do
6: V = V ∪ {(x, y) ∈ CCsub | (x, y) are points in equidistant intervals D}
7: for Each pair of nodes (u, v) ∈ V × V do
8: E = E ∪ (u, v) if the corresponding points are connected in S
9: return g
```

i am finding branch points and end points and mid points in between branch points and end points using `bwmorph` function this is my code.

```
clc;
clear all;
% read in a sample image -- also see letters.png, bagel.png
J=im2double(imread('i2.jpg'));

% Normalize and Binarization
b = imresize(J,[100,100]);
th = graythresh(b);
BW1 = im2bw(b, th);
figure;
imshowpair(b, BW1, 'montage');

% the standard skeletonization:
skelimg = bwmorph(~BW1,'thin',inf);

mn = bwmorph(skelimg,'branchpoints');
[row, column] = find(mn);
branchpts = [row column];
Endimg = bwmorph(skelimg,'endpoints');
[row,column] = find(Endimg);
Endpts = [row column];

n = size(Endpts,1);
Cntrpts = zeros(n,2);
for ii = 1:n
    % compute end & branch points geodesic distance transform
    dEnd = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, Endpts(ii,2), Endpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    [~,closestBranchIdx] = min(dEnd(mn));   
    dStart = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, branchpts(closestBranchIdx,2), branchpts(closestBranchIdx,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    D = dStart + dEnd;
    D = round(D *8) / 8;
    D(isnan(D)) = inf;
    paths = imregionalmin(D);
    % compute geodesic distance on found path from end point and divide max distance by 2 for center point
    dCenter = bwdistgeodesic(paths, Endpts(ii,2), Endpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    dCenter(isinf(dCenter)) = nan;
    c = nanmax(dCenter(:)) / 2;
    [~,centerPointIdx] = nanmin(abs(dCenter(:) - c));
    [yc,xc] = ind2sub(size(dCenter),centerPointIdx);
    Cntrpts(ii,:) = [yc,xc];
end
n = size(branchpts,1);
Cntrpts2 = zeros(n,2);
for ii = 1:n
    % compute end & branch points geodesic distance transform
    dEnd = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, branchpts(ii,2), branchpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    [~,closestBranchIdx] = min(dEnd(Endpts));   
    dStart = bwdistgeodesic(skelimg, Endpts(closestBranchIdx,2), Endpts(closestBranchIdx,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    D = dStart + dEnd;
    D = round(D * 2) / 2;
    D(isnan(D)) = inf;
    paths = imregionalmin(D);
    % compute geodesic distance on found path from end point and divide max distance by 2 for center point
    dCenter = bwdistgeodesic(paths, branchpts(ii,2), branchpts(ii,1), 'quasi-euclidean');
    dCenter(isinf(dCenter)) = nan;
    c = nanmax(dCenter(:)) / 2;
    [~,centerPointIdx] = nanmin(abs(dCenter(:) - c));
    [yc,xc] = ind2sub(size(dCenter),centerPointIdx);
    Cntrpts2(ii,:) = [yc,xc];
end
figure;imshow(skelimg);
hold on;
plot(Cntrpts(:,2),Cntrpts(:,1),'r.')
plot(Cntrpts2(:,2),Cntrpts2(:,1),'y.')
plot(branchpts(:,2),branchpts(:,1),'g.');
plot(Endpts(:,2),Endpts(:,1),'b.');
```

input image
[image: input image]

output image

[image: output image]

expected image
[image: expected input]

am not getting points in orientation parts or in loop to avoid this i want to traverse on white pixel on image after every two pixel i want add nodes and i want to connect edges to every nodes after adding the nodes i want to get the input image in graph as my expected image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Qud.jpg).

Comment: Have you tried **blackhat transform** ?

Comment: No, please give me some code.

Comment: I am able to depict the nodes approximately but not perfectly. I have not drawn the edges after that though... I have tried it in OpenCV using python....

Comment: I Am using matlab I do not know about openCV and Python.

Comment: Now am learning matlab and doing my project

Comment: You can try the same thing in MATLAB as well

Comment: OK thank you,  please give me some code it will help me to move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following OpenCV code is in python, alongside the explanation:

```
import cv2
filename = 'hindi.jpg'
img1 = cv2.imread(filename)  #--- Reading the image ---

img = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    #--- Converting to grayscale ---

ret, th = cv2.threshold(img, 160, 255, 1)  #--- Binary threshold ---
cv2.imshow('th.jpg', th)
```

[image]

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
dilate = cv2.morphologyEx(th, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, 3)  #--- Morphological dilation ---
cv2.imshow('dilate.jpg', dilate)
```

[image]

```
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(dilate, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, kernel)  #--- Performing blackhat morphology ---
cv2.imshow('blackhat.jpg', blackhat)
```

[image]

On performing dilation you can get:

[image]

```
ret, th1 = cv2.threshold(th, 127, 255, 1)  #--- Inverting the threshold image ---
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(th1, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, kernel)  #--- Performing tophat morphology ---
cv2.imshow('tophat.jpg', tophat)
```

[image]

On performing dilation you can get:

[image]

Comment: Hope it gets you started   :D

Comment: thank you for your concern, but in my algorithm i want to fix the D values, D value in the sense D = 2 or 3  i want to traverse on white pixels after every two or three pixels i want to insert a node. after traversing on white pixels i will get nodes on word image after getting the nodes on word image, i want to connect the corresponding nodes  for more clarification please go through my above algorithm i want to implement on the basis of the algorithm..

Comment: You can traverse using a `for` loop then

Comment: i want represent my input word image, in my expected word in my question

Comment: No am still struggling